# Где нужно в Repository подать другой Persistence по условию?

Tags: php, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, repository, persistence

Репозиторий осуществляет выборку данных по средством Persistence. Есть два Persistence . Например memoryи databese. Может даже есть memcahed.

Где нужно воткнуть условие что если memory Persistence вернул 0 то тогда иди к databese Persistence?
И ещё более важно в каком месте осуществиться кеширование из db в memory Persistence. Вернее где это делить правильнее с точки зрения ООП.

Приблизительный код:

```
class MyController{
    function postsAction(){
        $memoryRepository = new PostsRepository(new PostsMemoryPesistence());

        if( empty(  $posts = $memoryRepository->getAll()  ) ) {
            $posts =  (new PostsRepository(new PostsDBPesistence()))->getAll();
            $memoryRepository->save( $posts )
        }
    }
}

class PostsRepository{
    function __constructor(Presistence presistence){
        this->presistence = presistence;
    }

    function getAll(){
        return this->presistence->getAll();
    }

    function save( Posts[] $posts ){
        foreach($posts as $post){
        this->presistence->save( $post );
        }
    }
}

interface Presistence{
    function getAll();
    functions save();
}

class PostsMemoryPesistence implements Presistence{
    $data;
    function getAll(){}
    functions save(){}
}


class PostsDBPesistence implements Presistence{
    $db;
    function getAll(){}
    functions save(){}
}
```

На мой взгляд надо убрать логику условия и сохранения из контроллера. Вопрос куда?

Answer (score 0):

Общепринятая практика - разделение на *Сущность*, *Репозиторий*, *Сервис* и, при необходимости, *Контроллер*.

Comment: Сущность я опустил в данном вопросе. 
Если хотите :
   class PostsDBPesistence implements Presistence{
    $db;
      function getAll(){
           return array_map( function($post){ return new PostEntity($) }, $db->sqlQuery()->fetch()  )
      }
      functions save(){}
   }

Сервис я опустил. по сути сервис (в моем понимание) это место кода я могу скинуть логику их контроллера. ТЕ оно не будет сильно отличаться от примера. Будет if и save в сервисе а не в контроллере.Для вопроса это не имеет значение. Условие и кеширование не должно быть в сервисе

На мой вопрсо вы не дали ответа

Comment: Логика - в Сервис, сохранение - в Репозиторий...